# Evaluation order of positional and keyword arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments, python-internals, operator-precedence

Consider this contrived<sup>*</sup> example:

```
def count(one, two, three):
    print one
    print two
    print three
```

Three shall be the number thou shalt count, and the number of the counting
shall be three.

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> count(*map(int, x), three=x.pop())
1
2
3
```

Four shalt thou not count,

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> count(*map(int, x), three=x.pop())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: count() got multiple values for keyword argument 'three'
```

neither count thou two, excepting that thou then proceed to three.

```
>>> x = [1, 2]
>>> count(*map(int, x), three=x.pop())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: count() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Five is right out.

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> count(*map(int, x), three=x.pop())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: count() takes exactly 3 arguments (5 given)
```

After having read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17948369/4621513),
I would actually have thought that `x = [1, 2]` is the only one that works, because

- first, `map(int, x)` would be evaluated, `one` set to `1` and `two` set to `2`
- then, `x` still `[1, 2]`, `x.pop()` would be evaluated and `three` set to `2`, too.

My expectation for `x = [1, 2, 3]` was to get the error that I actually saw
for `x = [1, 2, 3, 4]`.

What is going on here? Why are the arguments seemingly not evaluated from left to right? Are keyword arguments evaluated first?

---

<sup>*</sup>actually my real code corresponds to `x = [1, 2, 3]`, which works, but I wasn't sure it was safe, and after reading the other question I thought it shouldn't actually work.

I'm using Python 2.7, if that matters.

Comment: You pop an element off so you are left with two args in the first example

Comment: But why do I `pop` before I `map`?

Comment: Because reasons. Honestly there's no obvious expected behavior here. If any of these worked I would consider it entirely luck and wouldn't rely on it. Write clearly and avoid mutation where possible otherwise it's very difficult to reason about what should happen.

Comment: The statement and the example following it below the "CPython implementation detail" seems relevant here: [Python Language Reference » Expressions » Calls](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls): "although the `*expression` syntax may appear *after* some keyword arguments, it is processed *before* the keyword arguments"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Python 2.7

If we look at the CPython source related to creating the AST([`ast_for_call`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/ast.c#l1978)) for a function call the order of argument evaluation turns out to be:

```
return Call(func, args, keywords, vararg, kwarg, func->lineno,
                func->col_offset, c->c_arena);
```

ie. args --> keywords --> vararg --> kwarg

So, in your case the keyword argument is evaluated first and then the star based expression(`vararg`) is evaluated.

**Byte code:**

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: func(1, 2, *('k', 'j', 'l'), z=1, y =2, three=x.pop(), **{kwarg:1}))
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (func)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)         # arg
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)         # arg
              9 LOAD_CONST               3 ('z')       # keyword
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             15 LOAD_CONST               4 ('y')       # keyword
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             21 LOAD_CONST               5 ('three')   # keyword
             24 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
             27 LOAD_ATTR                2 (pop)
             30 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             33 LOAD_CONST               9 (('k', 'j', 'l')) #vararg
             36 BUILD_MAP                1
             39 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             42 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (kwarg)     #kwarg
             45 STORE_MAP
             46 CALL_FUNCTION_V
```

Hence in your case the `pop()` call will happen first followed by the `varargs` evaluation.

So, if `three` is a part of `kwargs` then we will get an error with `map`:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> count(*map(float, x), **{'three': x.pop()})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-133-e8831565af13>", line 1, in <module>
    count(*map(float, x), **{'three': x.pop()})
TypeError: count() got multiple values for keyword argument 'three'
```

It will work if we do it *lazily:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> count(*(float(y) for y in x), **{'three': x.pop()})
1.0, 2.0, 3
```

<sub>*The reason why generator works and `map` or list comprehension fails is explained at the end.</sub>

---

### Python 3.5

The [`ast_for_call`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Python/ast.c#l2617) function here only maintains two lists: `args` and `keywords`.

Here the `varargs` are inserted into the args list and `kwargs` go to the `keywords` list. So, in the end the call looks like:

```
return Call(func, args, keywords, func->lineno, func->col_offset, c->c_arena);
```

**Byte code:**

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: func(1, 2, *('k', 'j', 'l'), z=1, y =2, three=x.pop(), **{kwarg:1}))
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (func)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              9 LOAD_CONST               9 (('k', 'j', 'l'))
             12 LOAD_CONST               6 ('z')
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             18 LOAD_CONST               7 ('y')
             21 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             24 LOAD_CONST               8 ('three')
             27 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
             30 LOAD_ATTR                2 (pop)
             33 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             36 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (kwarg)
             39 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             42 BUILD_MAP                1
             45 CALL_FUNCTION_VAR_KW   770 (2 positional, 3 keyword pair)
             48 RETURN_VALUE
```

Now things can get a little exciting if the expression yielding the `varargs` is lazy:

```
>> def count(one, two, three):
        print (one, two, three)
...
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> count(*map(float, x), three=x.pop())  # map is lazy in Python 3
1.0 2.0 3
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> count(*[float(y) for y in x], three=x.pop())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-25-b7ef8034ef4e>", line 1, in <module>
    count(*[float(y) for y in x], three=x.pop())
TypeError: count() got multiple values for argument 'three'
```

**Byte code:**

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: count(*map(float, x), three=x.pop()))
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (count)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (map)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (float)
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (x)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 ('three')
             18 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (x)
             21 LOAD_ATTR                4 (pop)
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             27 CALL_FUNCTION_VAR      256 (0 positional, 1 keyword pair)
             30 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(lambda: count(*[float(y) for y in x], three=x.pop()))
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (count)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x103b63930, file "<ipython-input-28-1cc782164f20>", line 1>)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('<lambda>.<locals>.<listcomp>')
              9 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
             15 GET_ITER
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             19 LOAD_CONST               3 ('three')
             22 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
             25 LOAD_ATTR                2 (pop)
             28 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             31 CALL_FUNCTION_VAR      256 (0 positional, 1 keyword pair)
             34 RETURN_VALUE
```

The lazy call works because unpacking(aka actual evaluation of the generator) doesn't happen until the function is actually called, hence in this case `pop()` call will remove the 3 first and then later on map will only pass 1, 2.

But, in the case of list comprehension the list object already contains 3 items and then even though `pop()` removed 3 later on we are still passing two values for the third argument.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed insight! So to summarize: It happens to work in CPython 2.7, but not in general in 3.5, except when using `map`; but it's an implementation detail and cannot be relied on?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It's not an implementation detail but a version detail, Python 2 and Python 3 are handling things differently. But across different implementation the output should match, for example I tested on PyPy 2.7.9 and it works same as CPython 2.7.10. Things have changed between Python 3.4 and 3.5 as well, for example now something like `count(*(1,), *(2, 3))` is valid(because of [PEP-448](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448)) in Python 3.5 but not in older versions of Python 3.x.